# Updating varchar has no effect

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update a varchar column with the update clause like this:

```
UPDATE ptl SET version=NULL WHERE version = 'a';
```

and MySQL gives me this answer:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected
```

I have several entries where the version is 'a' like for example this one:

```
Title        version
Hiper        a
```

And after my update statement it should turn into following:

```
Title        version
Hiper        NULL
```

but it does stay the same.

Why does it not change?

Comment: Are you sure there are no whitespaces in your `version`?

Comment: Try using  `where version like 'a'`  instead of `where version = 'a'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What looks like an "a" would not seem to be solely an `'a'`.  This can be for a variety of reasons.  Start with:

```
select length(ptl.version), ptl.version 
from ptl
where version like '%a%'
order by length(ptl.version);
```

You can see the length of the version being returned.

You might have other characters such as spaces in the value.  Or, you might have a utf character that happens to look like a lower-case a.  In the latter case, the above may not return anything.

Comment: yeah I think there was a trailing \r behind it. Now I was able to change it to NULL with my update clause but when I try to execute "select * from ptl where version = NULL" I get no rows? Even though it is NULL now

EDIT: okey I forgot to use IS NULL